# What is the point of proxy farming, specifically with singed?

Tags: league-of-legends

I see this a lot, but end up ignoring it and letting him do his own thing in toplane. I'm just wondering though, if he proxy farms, won't he die a lot? 
Isn't this going to benefit the enemy team?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is proxy farming?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122644/what-is-proxy-farming)

Comment: @HenryZhang that question does not address proxy farming as a generic strategy and only talks about singed. It does not address the bounty changes either.

Comment: The answer focuses on Singed because he has one of the best champion kits for proxy farming: good early waveclear for farming, a movement speed steroid to escape from enemies, and two forms of CC to further impede a chase. However, you are correct in noting that the bounty changes affected proxy farming -- the strat is much less effective now since a 0/10/0 player will still be worth gold as long as they farm well.

Answer (score 2):

The point of proxy farming is to provide a point of pressure on the map and to make it hard for your opponent to properly farm minions.

In the case of Singed in particular, he can clear entire waves pretty easily even very early in the game (level 1-3) compared to most champions, causing his lane opponents to have to try and fight the turret for last hits on minions (which is difficult early on when you have little to no bonus ad/ap).

This forces the enemy team to either respond and allow singed's team easy roaming or invading power, or to ignore it and singed will constantly be getting damage on the top lane turret by crashing minions into it. Either of these provide advantages to singed's team, and in the case of a good player, singed usually can escape early ganks using a combination of ghost, a slow/root, and a displacement ability which only leads to the enemy wasting further time, experience, and gold and gives your team a pressure advantage on the other side of the map.